# How to properly exclude all the files or just one in a given directory?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following directory structure:

```
$ tree config/
config/
├── config.ini
├── help.ini
└── services.yaml
```

This is part of a Git project but in the `.gitignore` file I am seeing the following:

```
config/*
/config/config.ini
config/config.ini
```

As a result the file `config/config.ini` is on the repository when it shouldn't be.

What's the right way to exclude all the files under `config/` and how to delete them from the upstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, delete (or move out of the repository) `config.ini` (+ any others you want to exclude) and make a commit.

Next, change your `.gitignore` to simply look like this:

```
config
```

(assuming `.gitignore` and `config/` are at the same level)

Commit the change for your `.gitignore` file.

All changes to anything in `config/` from here on out should not be tracked.